# How can I make validate with minimal one input with jquery validate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

My html code like this :

```
<form method="post" id="form-product">
    <input type="text" id="test-1" name="test[1]" /><br>
    <input type="text" id="test-2" name="test[2]" /><br>
    <input type="text" id="test-3" name="test[3]" /><br>
    <input type="text" id="test-4" name="test[4]" /><br>
    <input type="text" id="test-5" name="test[5]" /><br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My javascript code like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form-product').validate();
    $('[name^="test"]').each(function () {
        console.log('test')
        $(this).rules('add', {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: 'Minimal 1 input'
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Demo and full code like this : http://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/XTtTP/6/

I want to make the validation dynamic

If the user does not enter anything then the user submit, there will be a message "Minimal 1 input"

If user inputs in one textbox and submit then it will succeed.

The code I created is still not perfect

If user input in one textbox then submit, it still have message "Minimal 1 input". There should be no message

How I improve my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code makes them all required.  If you only want one field required out of the group, then you'll need to use the `require_from_group` rule instead.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form-product').validate();
    $('[name^="test"]').each(function () {
        console.log('test')
        $(this).rules('add', {
            require_from_group: [1, $('[name^="test"]')],
            messages: {
                require_from_group: 'Minimal 1 input'
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The `require_from_group` rule is part of the `additional-methods.js` file.

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/nw53mw17/](http://jsfiddle.net/nw53mw17/)**

I also suggest that you use the latest version(s) of the plugin.  Your jsFiddle is using the really old 1.10, but the latest version is 1.17; this is a substantial difference.

---

**EDIT**:

In order to group the messages together, use the `groups` option.  Since you don't know all the names before runtime, use an `.each()` to construct this parameter.

```
// dynamically construct groups parameter
var grp = "";
$('[name^="test"]').each(function () {
    grp += $(this).attr('name') + " ";
});
grp = $.trim(grp);
var myGroups = {TESTS: grp};

// intialize plugin with options
$('#form-product').validate({
    groups: myGroups
});
```

**DEMO 2:  [jsfiddle.net/nw53mw17/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/nw53mw17/2/)**

If you do not like the placement of this message on the form, use [the `errorPlacement` option](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement).

Please read the [online documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) for this plugin.

Comment: Okay. I will implement it to my case first

Comment: It seems it works. But if I open it first then I click submit, the message appears in all textbox. I want to set the position of the message, ie it is located at the above button submit and only 1 message. How can I do it?

Comment: @SuccessMan, although I already fully answered your original question, see my edit, which explains how to use the `groups` option.  If you want to move the message to another location, I will refer you to the `errorPlacement` option in the online documentation.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot :)